# Scope within a template

Tags: ember.js

I use the following template to display a table of all `users`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  <table>
    {{#each model itemController="user"}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        <td>
          {{#if isNew}}
            <button {{action 'save' this}} class="btn btn-small">Save</button>
            <button {{action 'discard' this}} class="btn btn-small">Discard</button>
          {{else}}
            {{#linkTo 'user.edit' this activeClass="disabled" classNames="btn btn-small"}}Edit{{/linkTo}}
          {{/if}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
  {{#unless newUserCreate}}
    <p>
      {{#linkTo 'users.new' classNames="btn btn-small"}}Create a new user{{/linkTo}}
    </p>
  {{/unless}}
</script>
```

Below the table I use a `{{#unless newUserCreate}}` which I'd like to use within the table too but because of a different scope I can't. How can I fix the following snippet to get it working? The `User` doesn't have a `newUserCreate`. Only the `Users` has.

```
{{#if isNew}}
  {{#unless newUserCreate}}
    <button {{action 'save' this}} class="btn btn-small">Save</button>
    <button {{action 'discard' this}} class="btn btn-small">Discard</button>
  {{/unless}}
{{else}}
  {{#linkTo 'user.edit' this activeClass="disabled" classNames="btn btn-small"}}Edit{{/linkTo}}
{{/if}}
```

**app.js**

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.createRecord();
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ into: 'users' });
  },

  activate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('users').set('newUserCreate', true);
  },

  deactivate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('users').set('newUserCreate', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you show more code around here `can't access the Users.get('newUserCreate') because of the {{#each model itemController="user"}}.`? it's not entirely clear how your setup is

Comment: Is it more clear now? Thanks for your time!

Comment: have you tried `{{#unless controller.newUserCreate}}`? or `{{#unless model.newUserCreate}}`, if this return null or undefined, then try to log the controller to inspect `{{log controller}}` the instance.